# Rails no routes match [DELETE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

So I'm trying to delete something in my database by making a fetch request in `ReactJS`, this will be hanled by `Rails API Mode`.

So this is how I fetch it in my front-end :

```
removeParticipationToContribution = id_request => {
        fetch(
            `http://localhost:3000/participants?id_request=${id_request}&user_id=${localStorage.getItem(
                'email'
            )}`,
            {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-User-Email': localStorage.getItem('email'),
                    'X-User-Token': localStorage.getItem('token')
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Here is the line of this route : 
`resources :participants, only: [:create, :show, :destroy]`

The problem here is that when I trigger this function, I get this error : 
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/participants"):`

Here is my `controller` :

```
def destroy
        participant = Participant.where(id_request: participant_params[:id_request], user_id: participant_params[:user_id]).first
        puts "---------------"
        puts params.inspect
        puts participant_params[:user_id]
    end

    private def participant_params
        params.permit(:id_request, :user_id)
    end
```

But it seems like he don't get to that `controller`.

I tried to do `http://localhost:3000/participants/destroy?id_request=...`
but that gave me a bunch of `unpermitted params` while those 2 params are permitted.

Comment: I already restarted everything. That command shows me the specific route : 
`DELETE /participants/:id(.:format)                                                              participants#destroy`

Comment: Ahh hang on, I see what you've done... One sec, answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DELETE` route (which you can see by running `rake routes | grep participants`) is expecting a route in the format:

```
DELETE /participants/:id(.:format) participants#destroy
```

However, you're trying to access the route:

```
http://localhost:3000/participants?id_request=(...)&user_id=(...)
```

This is not the same route. The `id` needs to be a route param, not a query param.

If this isn't the route format you'd like, then you can define it manually (i.e. don't just follow the standard convention that rails generated on your behalf).

*For example*, you may choose to use:

```
delete 'participants/:id_request/:user_id(.:format)', :to => 'participants#destroy'
```

Or:

```
delete 'participants(.:format)', :to => 'participants#destroy'
```

(...and then fail in the controller if a required param is missing)

But however you choose to do it, the route structure needs to match how you're calling it.